# Making a Plugin work based on URL Location

Tags: plugins

Is there any way to make my plugin work based on a URL instead of creating a page and attaching a shortcode? IE http://mysite.com/myplugin and that would bring up the starting page of the plugin

Comment: As far as i know the user would have to create a page and choose the page template for that page or integrate a shortcode into the pages / posts in order to retrive info but thats an intresting question.. waiting to see opinions on the subject

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "making the plugin work"? If a plugin is activated it always "works" (i.e. will be loaded). Do you mean enabling/disabling the display of its output dependent on URL? Please elaborate by editing your question. The more precise you are, the more likely will a correct answer be given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using the actions [generate_rewrite_rules](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/generate_rewrite_rules) & template_redirect

more info can be found at http://wp-fun.co.uk/2007/12/24/creating-custom-urls/#axzz1dXkrd62P

Comment: Thanks this is more or less what I was looking for. Its enough for me to adapt for what I'm hoping to do. My only real concern with this example is that its meant more if you were passing a option (Query Variable) into your plugin but worse case scenario I can just make it equal to 1.